# Apply OR constraint over the variables in a list

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

Suppose we have a list of variables. We want to apply a constraint over the variables, but the relation of these constraints are `or`. How we can do this in Eclipse CLP (prolog)?

We should notice that if the list is short like `A is [X, Y, Z]` the trivial solution is `A[0] #= 0 or A[1] #= 0 or A[2] #= 0` (if the constraint is equality to zero). Hence, this does not work for a long list.

Comment: In clpfd, there is (#\/)/2 for the general case. But often better consistency is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general reifiable constraints, you can reflect their truth value into a 0/1 variable, and sum these up.  E.g. to state that at least one element of `Xs` is greater than `3`:

```
( foreach(X,Xs),foreach(B,Bs)  do  B #= (X#>3) ),
sum(Bs) #> 0.
```

Another option is to remember that Prolog is good at meta-programming, so you could symbolically construct the expression `X1#>3 or X2#>3 or ... or Xn#>3` and then call it:

```
( foreach(X,Xs),fromto(0,Cs,(Cs or X#>3),Dis)  do  true ),
call(Dis).
```

For your specific example, where the constraint is "equal to zero" (or some other constant), it is actually easiest to use the global constraint [atleast/3](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic_global/atleast-3.html):

```
atleast(1, Xs, 0)              % at least 1 element of Xs is equal to 0
```

Comment: The result of `(foreach(X, [](1, 32, 6)), foreach(B, Bs) do B #= (X #> 3)), sum(Bs) #> 0.` is `No`.

Comment: @OmG *foreach* is for lists. To iterate over an array use *foreacharg*, i.e. `(foreacharg(X, [](1, 32, 6)), foreach(B, Bs) do B #= (X #> 3)), sum(Bs) #> 0.`